# Change target framework of a Office Addins project from .NET Framework to .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, office-js

The default `Excel Web Add-in` template created by Visual Studio in a new Office Addins solution has two projects:

- `AppName`: A manifest project, with only a XML file.
- `AppNameWeb`: A .NET Framework 4.6.1 project with several template files.

I want to delete the .NET Framework project and use a brand new .NET Core project instead, that I just created in the same solution.

I went to the project reference dialog of `AppName`. I removed `AppNameWeb` included my .NET Core project, then I confirmed the changes.

Now I get this warning:

*Project 'AppName.csproj' targets 'netcoreapp2.1'. It cannot be referenced by a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1'.*

I opened `AppName` project properties, but I don't have the option to change its target framework to `.NET Core 2.1`, it only lists `.NET Framework 4.x.x`

Question is: is it possible to change the target framework of a Office Addins project from .NET Framework to .NET Core? If it is not, how is the best way to work with Office Addins with ASP.NET Core?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow steps below for a workaround to achieve the same result:

1. Remove `AppNameWeb` and `AppNameWeb Core` projects reference from `AppName`
2. Specify `Web Project` of `AppName` project properties as `(None)`
3. Open `AppName.xml`, replace `~remoteAppUrl` with `AppNameWeb Core` home address
4. Set `SourceLocation` with home address like

   ```
   <DefaultSettings>
       <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:44382" />
   </DefaultSettings>
   ```
5. Right-Click solution -> Properties -> Configure Multiple startup projects with `AppName` and `AppNameWeb Core`
6. Startup multiple project to check the running.

Comment: Yes! It worked! Is it possible to "tell" the manifest that `~remoteAppUrl` is in fact the other localhost address instead replacing each occurance of its file?

Comment: @FelipeCostaGualberto I am afraid it is impossible, `~remoteAppUrl` is reset by the `Web Project`, for choosing `web project`, you will need to reference the `AppNameWeb Core` project will cause this reference error.

Comment: @Edward Sorry for bothering you, I don't understand the step 2, what is the 'Web Project of AppName project properties'? I wonder I should add a new property in the AppName project file, or change an existing property. Excuse me, could you let know the point in detail.